# Get information from mysql row

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know much of mysql and php and stuff but I'm trying to get if a value from the database is true or not. I know the name of the column in mysql, and it's called `verified`. Now there's a bit of code I've found which I think it is for calling this verified column from mysql

```
function SK_getUser($timeline_id=0, $all=false) {
    global $dbConnect, $sk;
    $timeline_id = SK_secureEncode($timeline_id);

    $query_two = "SELECT $subquery_one FROM " . DB_ACCOUNTS . " WHERE id=" .     $sql_fetch_one['id'] . " AND active=1";
        $sql_query_two = mysqli_query($dbConnect, $query_two);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($sql_query_two) == 1) {
        $sql_fetch_two = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_query_two);

        if (isset($sql_fetch_two['verified'])) {
            $sql_fetch_two['verified'] = ($sql_fetch_two['verified']==1) ? true : false;
        }

    }
}
```

I've seen this row being called too like this in the code

```
if ($sk['timeline']['verified'] == true) { 
// some code here
}
```

But when I try to call this function like this on other parts of the website it doesn't work. So I was trying to create this same action but be able to insert anywhere else on my website. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query_two);
if( isset($row['verified']) ){
   //TRUE
}else{
  //FALSE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start off, all php variables must start with $. in the first line DB_ACCOUNTS is without '$'.
Secondly, in the first line, "SELECT $subquery_one FROM " there you try to select a column, but you seem to be invoking a php variable since it starts with '$'

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have boolean types. It has a column type that *pretends* it's boolean, but it's really just a one-digit integer that can be 0 or 1. The key bit in the code you've pasted is:

```
$sql_fetch_two['verified'] = ($sql_fetch_two['verified']==1) ? true : false;
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
if( $sql_fetch_two['verified'] == 1 ) {
  $sql_fetch_two['verified'] = true;
} else {
  $sql_fetch_two['verified'] = false;
}
```

`?:` is the [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), which is essentially shorthand for `if/else` blocks.

Anyhow, the conversion from an integer to a boolean type isn't strictly necessary in PHP because of [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).